# How to delete an autoscaling group and launch configuration or launch template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Auto scaling groups can be associated with either launch configurations (LC) or launch templates (LT). I am trying to delete an autoscaling group and its associated LC or LT. Is there an easy way to do this?

It does not seem like there is an option to automatically delete the LC/LT when using `aws autoscaling delete-auto-scaling-group` ([delete-auto-scaling-group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/delete-auto-scaling-group.html)).

Therefore, it seems I need to use `aws ec2 delete-launch-template` ([delete-launch-template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/delete-launch-template.html)) and/or `aws autoscaling delete-launch-configuration` ([delete-launch-configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/delete-launch-configuration.html)).

If I have an autoscaling group name, how do I get the associated LC/LT?

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming-related question, so it is off-topic for SO. That said, like most things in the CLI, [there is a `describe` command for ASGs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-groups.html) that returns a `LaunchConfigurationName` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this can only be done with a script. Here is what I did:

```
#! /bin/bash

set -ex

# get launch configuration name or launch template id
my_lc=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --no-paginate --output text --query AutoScalingGroups[?AutoScalingGroupName==\'${MY_ASG_NAME}\'].LaunchConfigurationName)

my_lt=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --no-paginate --output text --query AutoScalingGroups[?AutoScalingGroupName==\'${MY_ASG_NAME}\'].LaunchTemplate.LaunchTemplateId)

# delete ASG
aws autoscaling delete-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name ${MY_ASG_NAME} --force-delete

# delete launch configs if they exist
aws autoscaling delete-launch-configuration --launch-configuration-name ${my_lc} || true # Don't exit script if command fails

# delete launch templates if they exist
aws ec2 delete-launch-template --launch-template-name ${my_lt} || true # Don't exit script if command fails
```